# NetApp SVM management web interface 404 error

Tags: netapp

I created an SVM with the intentions of delegating administration to just that SVM (my first time doing this). I created an aggregate for it, created an SVM, assigned the aggregate to the SVM, created a separate account for the SVM and assigned it a management LIF. I can access the SVM via SSH and that seems to be working fine. But the web interface for the SVM gives a 404 error:
Not Found
The requested URL /sysmgr was not found on this server.

When I check the services of the vServer, it does not have a "sysmgr" service like the SVM for cluster management. But none of the data SVMs in the cluster have that service either. I can't find a way to add that service to the particular vServer.

Is it possible that when you delegate administration of an SVM only (as opposed to the whole cluster) that it is only administrable via SSH? Any ideas on what I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SVM management is not available through HTTP; only SSH and ONTAPAPI.
https://docs.netapp.com/ontap-9/topic/com.netapp.doc.onc-sm-help-960/GUID-E96BB995-447A-4B53-9CBB-C829C76851C6.html